# Get the values from the following json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json like this:

```
a = [{"pk": 1, "model": "gps.test", "fields": {"hi": 23.1, "hello": 47.916142}}]
```

I want values of `pk`, `hi` and `hello`;

Tried various ways like:

```
a['pk']
a.pk
```

None is working. What's wrong?

Comment: `a` is an *array* with one object item!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, parse your JSON with `JSON.parse(json)`.

`a` is an array, so grab the first element and then grab the keys from the `fields` object.

```
a[0].fields.hi
a[0].fields.hello
```

If you have more than one object in the array:

```
a[i].fields.hi
a[i].fields.hello
```

where `i` is the index of the element in the array.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qZ9b/1/)

Comment: `alert(a[0])` yields `[` and your solutions yields `fields not defined.`

Comment: No it doesn't. See my jsfiddle.

Comment: What you've got is a JS object. JSON is serialised JS data. I've rewritten the jsfiddle to show you what I mean.

Comment: Oh Shit man, I forgot to parse. Thanks for the input. I will accept your answer whenever I can. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

a is an array so you need to take at specific index

```
a[0].pk
```

Comment: It gets me nothing however, if I do `a[0]` the result is `[`. I am pretty sure its coming as string, don't know why.

Comment: be sure what a contains